# What causes differences in estimates of 95%CI of the mean across subgroups in Stata?

Tags: confidence-interval, stata, mean

In the small reproducible example, I'm calculating mean of a variable across three groups:

```
sysuse auto, clear
drop if rep78 < 3 | mi(rep78)
la de rep78 3 "Three" 4 "Four" 5 "Five"
la val rep78 rep78

mean mpg if foreign, over(rep78)
mean mpg, over(rep78 foreign)
```

The results are identical when it comes to means, but the CIs differ. First method:

```
. mean mpg if foreign, over(rep78)

Mean estimation                   Number of obs   =         21

        Three: rep78 = Three
         Four: rep78 = Four
         Five: rep78 = Five

--------------------------------------------------------------
        Over |       Mean   Std. Err.     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+------------------------------------------------
mpg          |
       Three |   23.33333   1.452966       20.3025    26.36417
        Four |   24.88889   .9043789      23.00239    26.77539
        Five |   26.33333   3.122499      19.81991    32.84675
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Versus second:

```
. mean mpg, over(rep78 foreign)

Mean estimation                   Number of obs   =         59

         Over: rep78 foreign
    _subpop_1: Three Domestic
    _subpop_2: Three Foreign
    _subpop_3: Four Domestic
    _subpop_4: Four Foreign
    _subpop_5: Five Domestic
    _subpop_6: Five Foreign

--------------------------------------------------------------
        Over |       Mean   Std. Err.     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+------------------------------------------------
mpg          |
   _subpop_1 |         19   .7862783      17.42609    20.57391
   _subpop_2 |   23.33333   1.452966      20.42491    26.24176
   _subpop_3 |   18.44444   1.528535      15.38475    21.50414
   _subpop_4 |   24.88889   .9043789      23.07858     26.6992
   _subpop_5 |         32          2      27.99657    36.00343
   _subpop_6 |   26.33333   3.122499      20.08297    32.58369
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

What is causing such behavior? Which method is more appropriate?

Comment: _What_ is causing such behavior is the choice of the degrees of freedom for the t distribution from which the quantiles necessary to the calculation of the Cis are derived. For example, in your first example `26.33333 - invttail(20, .025)*3.122499=19.819911`, while in your second example `26.33333 - invttail(58, .025)*3.122499=20.082969`

Comment: @boscovich Thanks, didn't spot this one. Please convert the comment to an answer so that we can upvote/accept it.